# Anyway to rotate marquee label?

Tags: ios, swift

Hey I implemented marquee label into my project with cocoa pods but have been unsuccessful in getting it to rotate.

```
let newsFeed: MarqueeLabel = MarqueeLabel(
    frame: CGRect(x:15, y:66, width:28, height:159)) 
newsFeed.textAlignment = .right newsFeed.text = "TEXT" 
self.view.addSubview(newsFeed) 
newsFeed.transform = CGAffineTransform(
    rotationAngle: CGFloat(-(Double.pi / 2.0))) 
newsFeed.frame = CGRect(x:15, y:66, width:28, height:159)
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65398188/edit) your question instead of putting it in a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You should:

- Set the height and width of your field to the *unrotated* height and
  width when you create it:
- Not try to manipulate the frame once you've changed the view's
  transform. Instead you should set the view's center: To quote Apple's
  docs on UIView.transform:

> **Warning** When the value of this property is anything other than the
> identity transform, the value in the frame property is undefined and
> should be ignored.

I don't know what a `MarqueeLabel` is, but this code using a vanilla `UILabel` works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let startingFrameRect = CGRect(x:15, y:66, width:159, height:28)
        let newsFeed = UILabel(
            //Create the label wide and short as if it is not rotated.
            frame: startingFrameRect)
        newsFeed.text = "Some Text"
        self.view.addSubview(newsFeed)
        newsFeed.transform = CGAffineTransform(
            rotationAngle: CGFloat(-(Double.pi / 2.0)))
        //Add a border so you can see the label's rotated frame
        newsFeed.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        //Adjust the view's center based on it's origin, but exchanging height and width
        newsFeed.center = CGPoint (x: startingFrameRect.origin.x + startingFrameRect.size.height / 2,
                                   y: startingFrameRect.origin.y + startingFrameRect.size.width / 2)
        
        //Also add a view to show where the unrotated view would land.
        let boxView = UIView(frame: startingFrameRect)
        boxView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        boxView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        self.view.addSubview(boxView)
    }
}
```